# Override Index Return in C# Collection

Tags: c#, overriding

I am adding functionality to an existing .Net collection.  In order to do this, I am overriding several functions.  I have not been able to override the return value of the basic array return in the collection.  For example, if I call emailMessage.To[i], it does not return the proper value, but if I call emailMessage.Item(i), it returns the correct value.  Below is the code from my class.  What do I need to override to correct the first error?

```
namespace EmailService
{
    public class MailAddressCollection : System.Net.Mail.MailAddressCollection
    {
        public MailAddressCollection() : base()
        {
        }

        public void Add(MailAddress Address)
        {
             base.Add(Address);
        }

        public MailAddress Item(int index)
        {
            return (MailAddress)(base.Items[index]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: See this question:
[How do I overload the square-bracket operator in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287928/how-do-i-overload-the-square-bracket-operator-in-c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I overload the square-bracket operator in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287928/how-do-i-overload-the-square-bracket-operator-in-c)

Comment: I think it's better to use composition instead of inheritance in this case to adhere to the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public MailAddress this[int index] 
{
   get { return ((MailAddress)(base.Items[index]); }
}
```

Comment: @Brian: it can be hidden with the 'new' keyword.

Comment: I needed the new keyword.  "public new MailAddress this[int index]"

Answer (score 8):

You are a little bit out of luck, because MailAddressCollection doesn't set the indexer as virtual.

You CAN use the new keyword:

```
public new MailAddress this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        return base[index];    
    }           
}
```

But, your indexer will only work if you have a reference to YOUR collection type.  If you use polymorphism, your indexer will not get called.

Answer (score 0):

Or alternatively

```
    public MailAddress this[int index]
    {
        get { return base[index] as MailAddress; }
    }
```