# Basic C# class question regarding the "this" keyword

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I'm going through someone else's code and I saw this statement:

```
public CustomClassName this [ string varName]
```

Please excuse the newbness of this question, but the square brackets threw me off.
Is this a method or constructor?

How does the "this" variable work in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called an indexer. [MSDN page.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx)

Comment: So that's how it's done! VB.NET's `Default` is a lot more clear :)

Comment: @minitech: Highly debatable.  I haven't come across a single construct  in VB that I thought was more clear than it's C# allegory.

Answer (score 1):

Neither, it's an [Indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx). It allows you to do CustomClassName[ obj ] and retrieve a value from the object.

Answer (score 0):

It is an indexer, so you can access the class similar to an array.

Answer (score 0):

It is defining an index operator on your type.  Take for example, the `List<T>` class.  The library designers wanted you to be able to write code like this:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int x = list[2]; // x == 3
```

The syntax that accomplishes that is what you have posted above.  So, for your own types, you can...

```
class NameCollection : /* whatever */
{
    private List<string> _names = new List<string> { "Ed", "Sally", "John" };

    public string this[int index]
    {
        get { return _names[index]; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is simply an overload of the square-bracket operator in C#.

see here:

[How do I overload the square-bracket operator in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287928/how-do-i-overload-the-square-bracket-operator-in-c)