# How to override or create custom behavior for brackets "[]" in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I overload the square-bracket operator in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287928/how-do-i-overload-the-square-bracket-operator-in-c)

Basically I want to know if there is a way to achieve custom behavior for brackets similar to the SqlDataReader Object.  For example with the SqlDataReader object you can use an index number "Reader[0]" which is the normal operation for brackets, or you can supply the column name "Reader["id"]".  I know how to override basic operators but can not seem to find anything relating to changing bracket behavior.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to define an indexer in your type

```
public class MyType {
  public string this[int index] {
    get { 
      switch (index) {
        case 1: return "hello";
        case 2: return "world";
        default: return "not found";
      }
    }
    set { ... }
  }
}

MyType t = ...;
Console.WriteLine(t[0]);  // hello
Console.WriteLine(t[1]);  // world
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.  Sorry for the duplicate question, I keep getting strange results when I tried searching for [].