# Accessing a Collection

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a class where you can access a collection in it and get an item using a string index, (I hope this makes sense), basically I would like to know either what this is called or how to do it?

here is an example of what I mean;

```
string blah = SomeClass.Items["Item1"].ToString();
```

Hopefully someone can make some sense of this.

Thank You.

Comment: I guess it makes sense but how do you determine what the string name is? You can make your indexers do and return anything you want.

Comment: It's probably a `Dictionary<string, string>`. Or you can implement your own collection. The indexer (the square brackets) is implemented as the 'this' property. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287928/how-do-i-overload-the-square-bracket-operator-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx).

> Indexers allow instances of a class or struct to be indexed just like arrays. Indexers resemble properties except that their accessors take parameters.

In your case you want to index using a string. Something like this:

```
public MyItem this[string index]
{
    get { return ... }
}
```

It may be that you would be better off removing the `Items` layer from your syntax. That would result in your code reading like this:

```
string blah = SomeClass["Item1"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean a [string indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx).

> Indexers allow instances of a class or struct to be indexed just like arrays. Indexers resemble properties except that their accessors take parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`Dictionary<string, string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wrapper around a List to get the "Items" property.

```
public class MyClass
{

  private readonly List<string> _myColl = new List<string>();

  public List<string> Items
  { 
    get { return this._myColl; }
  }

}
```

You can then use it like so:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
c.Items.Add("something");
```

If you need a string key, you can always switch `List to Dictionary<string, string>`

```
public class MyClass
{

  private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _myColl = new Dictionary<string, string>();

  public Dictionary<string, string> Items
  { 
    get { return this._myColl; }
  }

}
```

Then use it like so:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
c.Items.Add("somekey", "somevalue");
```

I guess the point is that you can wrap just about any collection with this pattern to fit almost any need.

Answer (score 0):

As people have said, an indexed property is one option. Tutorial here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288464(v=vs.71).aspx