# Overload [] operator in C# and give more than one return value

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I overload the square-bracket operator in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287928/how-do-i-overload-the-square-bracket-operator-in-c)

**For a class is it possible to overload the operator [] in C#?**

If so what is the correct syntax to declare the [] overloaded function?

*Also can the operator [] returns different data types based off the parameter given? If not, what do you think is my other solution? Should I use Object instead?*

```
public class MyClass {

     private Dictionary<string,Element> eAttribs;
     private Dictionary<string,string> defAttribs;

     // Also can the operator [] returns different data types based off the parameter given?
     // If not, what do you think is my other solution?
     public Element operator[](string attribKey) {
         if (eAttribs.containsKey(attribKey)
            return eAttribs[attribKey];
         else return null;
     }

     // COMPILE Error below: Unexpected symbol '['
     public string operator[](string attribKey) {
         if (defAttribs.containsKey(attribKey)
            return defAttribs[attribKey];
         else return null;
     }
}
```

Comment: You can emulate it by differing parameter count to indexer. See my answer and the demo at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In c# these are called indexers.

Syntax:

```
public object this[int key]
{
    get
    {
        return GetValue(key);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(key,value);
    }
}
```

You can return only one object. Use a base class instead for all the type objects you have to return.

Answer (score 2):

> For a class is it possible to overload the operator [] in C#?

Yes. The syntax is to overload the `this[]` property ([“indexer”](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx)):

```
public Element this[string attribKey] {
    get { … }
    set { … }
}
```

> Also can the operator [] returns different data types based off the parameter given?

No, unfortunately not. C# generally forbids overload resolution based on return type; it only considers argument types.

Answer (score 1):

You could return object or use [dynamic Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx)

```
public dynamic this[string key]
{
     get 
     {
         //return value;
     }
     set
     {
         //set value; 
     }
}
```