# Accessing List<MyClass> through string index

Tags: c#

If I have

```
List<MyClass> MyObj;
```

I can access specific member like this:

```
MyObj[0] = new MyClass();
```

But some time ago, somewhere on msdn I have read, that it is possible to access my objects like that:

```
MyObj["mykey"] = new MyClass();
```

Is that possible, or am I making things up here?

Answer (score 9):

In `List` it's not possible, because it only has `int` indexer (`this[int index]`) which allows to get object by index.

For this you should use `Dictionary<string, MyClass>`, which will allow you to get objects by key e.g.:

```
MyDictionary["MyKey"] = new MyClass();
```

[MSDN Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Not directly since a `List<T>` has only an `int` indexer. However, if you want to lookup an object via a property you could use LINQ:

```
MyClass obj = MyObj.FirstOrDefault(c => c.SomeProp == "mykey");
if(obj != null)
{
   // yes
}
```

another approach is to use  a [`Dictionary<string, MyClass>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)(key must be unique):

```
MyClass obj;
if(MyObjDictionary.TryGetValue("mykey", out obj))
{
    // yes
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many different types where the indexer takes a string. You were probably looking at a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Well, this may be possible with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287928/how-do-i-overload-the-square-bracket-operator-in-c) override, like :

```
public class MyClass : List<int> 
{
    public int this[string key] {
        get {
            return this.Where(x=>x==int.Parse(key)).SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

so in code you will use it like:

```
  var a = new MyClass() {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}; 
  a["5"]; //this will return 5 integer
```

No need for any dictionary or additional datastructures.  Worth mantionig that in this case you *may* have performance issues on large collections, but if your collection is small enough, go with this.