# C# convert list<object> to list<dynamic> and add properties

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, expandoobject

In c# I wanted to convert List to List
and add new properties to object dynamically.

```
List<Customer> customerList; // has list of customer object
List<Properties> properties; // has { string:propertyname and string:value}
```

I wanted to add some properties dynamically to all customer object by iterating through the list similar to that of javascript in C# without loosing data in existing list of objects

I would get properties from other source.

How do I achieve this kind of behavior in C#.

```
for(Customer c in customerList)
{
  for(Property prop in properties)
   {
      c[prop.propertyName]=prop.value; // similar to javascript 
   }   
}
```

I would require this List to be accessed from my UI by making an API call and return the data in JSON format

Comment: I could add  public dynamic custom = new ExpandoObject(); to Customer
and iterate customers and 
var cust = customers[i];
                       var exp = item.custom as IDictionary<String, object>;
                       exp[cust.propertyName] = cust.value ?? string.Empty;
But is there a way where I could add properties to Customer instead of a property inside customer.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't. I'd keep my list as a list of `Customer` and I would extend my `Customer` class to support access to a `Dictionary` of additional properties, accessible through an [explicit indexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287928/how-do-i-overload-the-square-bracket-operator-in-c).

```
private Dictionary<string,Something>;
public Something this[string i]
{
    get { return InnerDictionary[i]; }
    set { InnerDictionary[i] = value; }
}
```

Comment: I would require this List to be accessed from my UI by making an API call and return the data in JSON format, so that's why I wanted it to be in Object format