# I want to use `[]` to check if a string exists in an array or not

Tags: c#

Currently my code is like that

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    private static string[] words = new string[] { "Word1","Word2","Word3","Word4","Word5" };

    public static bool IsExist(string Word)
    {
        return words.Any(w => w == Word);
    }
}
```

And am calling that as

```
ExampleClass.IsExist("Word1"); //Returns true
ExampleClass.IsExist("WordNotExist"); //Returns false
```

But i want to call like this

```
ExampleClass.IsExist["Word1"]; //Returns true
ExampleClass.IsExist["WordNotExist"]; //Returns false
```

*How should i modify my class to do so please help me out*

Comment: Why do you want that? It isn't an array, right?

Comment: I see no reason for that, and you cannot declare an indexed property in static class.

Comment: no problem my code is compleately diffrent. please give me any idea what i have to do to accomplish this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are going really bad here since using an indexer to call a method is just wrong. And with that, you can't have indexers on static classes.

That said, this is how it does work:

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    public class IsExistHelper
    {
        private static string[] words = new string[] { "Word1", "Word2", "Word3", "Word4", "Word5" };

        public bool this[string Word]
        {
            get
            {
                return words.Any(w => w == Word);
            }
        }
    }

    public static IsExistHelper IsExist { get; } = new IsExistHelper();
}
```

I have used an inner class to create a helper, which creates your property name. Inside there is an indexer that has your original code.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would want to do it that way, but:

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    private string[] words = new string[] { "Word1", "Word2", "Word3", "Word4", "Word5" };

    public bool this[string Word]
    {
        get { return words.Any(w => w == Word); }
    }
}
```

It must be called with an instance:

```
var _ = new ExampleClass();
var isTrue = _["Word1"] == true
```

Unfortunately you **cannot** do it with a `static` member. Alternatively you need to create an indexer inside an auxillary class that's instance name is `IsExist`.

My opinion is that you should leave it as it is.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve it exactly the way you want it (even though in my opinion it isn't a good design) use an inner class that will override the `[]` operator and will check your condition. Then in your original class have a property of that inner class.

*Keep in mind that when overriding the `[]` operator you can't be using a static* class.

See that instead of using `Any` you can just use `Contains` - because you are checking for the entire object itself it is a cleaner way to do so

```
public static class ExampleClass
{

    public class InnerIsExist
    {
        private string[] words = new string[] { "Word1", "Word2", "Word3", "Word4", "Word5" };

        public bool this[string word]
        {
            get {  return words.Contains(word); }
        }
    }

    public static InnerIsExist IsExist { get; } = new IsExistClass();
}
```

Use:

```
var doesItContain = ExampleClass.IsExist["b"]; // false
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are calling a function and its as simple as declaring it, but for square brackets, **you will have to overload them**. Here is a helpful link: [How do I overload the square-bracket operator in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287928/how-do-i-overload-the-square-bracket-operator-in-c)

Basically, in your case it should look like this:

```
public bool this[string Word]
{
    get { return words.Any(w => w==Word); }
}
```

I haven't tested the code, so let me know if it works.